# Need Help Choosing A Surf Board

Tags: surfing

I really enjoy surfing and would say that I am intermediate level or definitely over the beginner curve. Anyway I am looking at these 4 boards right now and need to know what experience you guys have had with them if any!

- Roberts White Diamond
- Lost Subdriver
- Firewire Dominator
- Channel Islands Fishcuit

These seem most suited to the waves here in SoCal and they seem super carvy like a longboard skateboard (which I also ride) Right now I am leaning towards the Roberts White Diamond. I would love some other input though from you guys.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are pretty much off topic across the entire SE community, as they are generally too subjective to be "constructive." What is best for you depends on YOU.

Comment: A better question would probably be along the lines of "I'm looking for XYZ experience on my surfboard. What characteristics should I look for to accomplish this?"

Comment: Two questions you should probably read on board length and fin selection: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/1411/66 http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/498/66

Comment: As mentioned, shopping questions are generally discouraged on the SE network. If you edit it into a more constructive question as Flimzy says, without making it a duplicate of the questions Rory linked, flag it to let us moderators know and we'll see about re-opening it.